# when i click on checkbox then i want to show or hide a div using bootstrap and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
<script type="javascript">
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  /* which function */
  
  
  
  
  </script>
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Registration.aspx.cs" Inherits="Practical_5.View.Registration" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div style="background-color: red; font-size: x-large; font-weight: bold; text-align: center"><span>You are registering for Matrimony Meet "Matrimonial Get Together - Pune - 22-Aug-2015"</span></div>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <img src="../Images/BJS_Logo-hindi.png" alt="logo" style="height: 71px; width: 161px" />
                        <label class="pull-right" style="font-size: x-large">Register</label>
                    </div>


                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="mname">Middle Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mname" placeholder="Middle Name" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="sell">Gender</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                                        <option>Select</option>
                                        <option>Male</option>
                                        <option>Female</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="mnunber">Mobile Number</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mnumber" placeholder="Mobile Number" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <label>India</label>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" value="" />India</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


when i checked or select this checkbox then i want to show the div having id=div1. and when i unchecked or unselect the checkbox then i want show the div
having id=div2

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label>Address</label>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div id="div1" class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="state">State</label>
                                            <select class="form-control" id="State">
                                                <option class="active">Select State</option>
                                                <option>Maharashtra</option>
                                                <option>Andhra Pradesh</option>
                                                <option>Gujrat</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="city">City</label>
                                            <select class="form-control" id="city">
                                                <option class="active">Select city</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
when i select the option maharashtra in dropdown list having id state
then i want display all the cities in maharashtra in another dropdown list
having id city????
please help me
                                 <div id="div2" class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="state">State</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Text2" placeholder="Enter State" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="city">City</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Text3" placeholder="Enter City" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="zip">Country</label>
                                            <select class="form-control" id="Select1">
                                                <option class="active">Select Country</option>
                                                <option>India</option>
                                                <option>US</option>
                                                <option>Singapore</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="zip">Zip</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" placeholder="Enter Zip" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <%--<div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="row">
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                            </div>
                        </div>--%>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="lid">Login ID</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lid" placeholder="Login ID" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="pwd">Password</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Password" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="cpwd">Conform Password</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cpwd" placeholder="Conform Password" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-5"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Register Me!</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


how i should do this.
which function i should write in javascript??
please help me

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

Comment: when i select the option maharashtra in dropdown list having id state
then i want display all the cities in maharashtra in another dropdown list
having id city????
please help me

Answer (score 2):

First, give `id` to your checkbox :

```
<input value="" type="checkbox" onclick="Change()" id="India" />
```

Then add `id` and `style="visibility:hidden;"` to your div like :

```
<div id="div1"  style="visibility:hidden;"><p>blabla</p></div>
```

And the function would be something like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Change() {

if ((document.getElementById('India').checked)) {
 document.getElementById('div1').style.visibility="visible";
}
else {
document.getElementById('di1v').style.visibility="hidden";
}
}
</script>
```

Of course, you have to adapt the code but it would solve your problem

Comment: when i select the option maharashtra in dropdown list having id state
then i want display all the cities in maharashtra in another dropdown list
having id city????
please help me

Comment: I don't understand. You want to link two dropdown lists ?

Comment: in above code there are div having id div1. in that div there are two dropdown list one for state and one for city. suppose i select one option in state dropdown list eg. i select state maharashtra then i want display all the cities of maharashtra in another dropdown list which is city. how i should do this?????

Comment: I understand but this is not your initial question, in a comment section I cannot write proper code ^^

Comment: i added the new question please help me

Comment: In your second dropdown list, you should use something like `NameList1 =   document.getElementById('DropDown1').value` then add a querry filling automaticaly the second listbox

Comment: i added new question.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <input value="" type="checkbox" onChange="toggleDiv()" />

<div id="Pakistan"  style="display:none;"><p>ShowHide</p></div>
```

> ```
> In your Javascript code
> ```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleDiv() {

// first check if display then hide otherwise show
if ((document.getElementById('Pakistan').style.display == 'none')) {
 document.getElementById('Pakistan').style.display="block";
}
else {
document.getElementById('Pakistan').style.display="none";
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: when i select the option maharashtra in dropdown list having id state
then i want display all the cities in maharashtra in another dropdown list
having id city????
please help me

Answer (score 1):

Editing the whole code into Javascript

```
                /*Get the states and city in javascript. Its preferred over for easy Coding.*/
            var states = [{"state":"Maharashtra","cities":["Andheri","Banda"]},{"state":"Andhra Pradesh","cities":["Hydreabad"]},{"state":"Gujrat","cities":["Surat"]}]
            var country = document.getElementById("country");
            var state = document.getElementById("State");
            var city = document.getElementById("city");
            var divOne = document.getElementById("div1");
            var divTwo = document.getElementById("div2");
            var stateslength = states.length;

/*Initialize the document */
            (function(){
                country.checked = false;
                divOne.style.display="none";
                var stateoptions = "<option value='' selected>Select a state</option>";
                for(var i=0; i< stateslength;i++){
                  stateoptions =stateoptions+'<option value="'+states[i].state+'">'+states[i].state+'</option>';
                };
                state.innerHTML=stateoptions;
            }());

            function toggleCountry(){
                alert("asdf");
                if(country.checked){
                    divOne.style.display="block";
                    divTwo.style.display="none";         
                }
                else{
                    divOne.style.display="none";
                    divTwo.style.display="block";

                }   
            };

            function getCity(){

                for (i = city.length; i >=0; i--) {
                        city.remove(i);
                    }

                var cityoptions = "<option value='' selected>Select a City</option>";
                for(var i = 0; i < stateslength; i++){

                        if(states[i].state == state.value){
                                var totalCities = states[i].cities.length;
                            for(j= 0; j<totalCities; j++ ){
                               cityoptions = cityoptions + '<option value="'+states[i].cities[j]+'">'+states[i].cities[j]+'</option>';
                            }
                            break;
                        }

                }
                city.innerHTML=cityoptions;   
            }
```

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/tb4xy78a/8/)

Edit 2:

Updated JSFIDDLE to load js on no wrap-body

Comment: Happy to help. If this is the code, please pick this as a right answer.